# How to download Google Drive files to a Jupyter notebook using the Google Drive Python API?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download my Google Drive files to a Jupyter notebook using the Google Drive Python API. Thus, I'm following this [post](https://medium.com/@umdfirecoml/a-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-download-your-google-drive-data-to-your-jupyter-notebook-using-the-52f4ce63c66c). But since this is outdated, I'm having problems when creating the credential using OAuth 2.0 verification.

Since Jupyter notebook opens a localhost URL, I decided to configure it as a Web Application for the Type of Application. Then, I'm not sure about what to configure on the `JavaScript authoritative sources` and `Authorized redirect URIs` fields. I guess that in the first field, I could use the local host URL when opening a Jupyter notebook. In the case of the second field, I don't know what to put on it. The configuration was done as follows.[image: config_image].

When running the code suggested on the Medium post:

```
obj = lambda: None
lmao = {"auth_host_name":'localhost', 'noauth_local_webserver':'store_true', 'auth_host_port':[8080, 8090], 'logging_level':'ERROR'}
for k, v in lmao.items():
    setattr(obj, k, v)
    
# authorization boilerplate code
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
# The following will give you a link if token.json does not exist, the link allows the user to give this app permission
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, obj)
```

I’m getting this error: `InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web"`, regarding to the redirect URI that I don't know how to configure.

```
InvalidClientSecretsError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 12
     10 # The following will give you a link if token.json does not exist, the link allows the user to give this app permission
     11 if not creds or creds.invalid:
---> 12     flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
     13     creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, obj)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/py-3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:133, in positional.<locals>.positional_decorator.<locals>.positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    131     elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    132         logger.warning(message)
--> 133 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/py-3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py:2134, in flow_from_clientsecrets(filename, scope, redirect_uri, message, cache, login_hint, device_uri, pkce, code_verifier, prompt)
   2097 """Create a Flow from a clientsecrets file.
   2098 
   2099 Will create the right kind of Flow based on the contents of the
   (...)
   2131                                              invalid.
   2132 """
   2133 try:
-> 2134     client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(filename,
   2135                                                       cache=cache)
   2136     if client_type in (clientsecrets.TYPE_WEB,
   2137                        clientsecrets.TYPE_INSTALLED):
   2138         constructor_kwargs = {
   2139             'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
   2140             'auth_uri': client_info['auth_uri'],
   2141             'token_uri': client_info['token_uri'],
   2142             'login_hint': login_hint,
   2143         }

File ~/.pyenv/versions/py-3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py:165, in loadfile(filename, cache)
    162 _SECRET_NAMESPACE = 'oauth2client:secrets#ns'
    164 if not cache:
--> 165     return _loadfile(filename)
    167 obj = cache.get(filename, namespace=_SECRET_NAMESPACE)
    168 if obj is None:

File ~/.pyenv/versions/py-3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py:126, in _loadfile(filename)
    123 except IOError as exc:
    124     raise InvalidClientSecretsError('Error opening file', exc.filename,
    125                                     exc.strerror, exc.errno)
--> 126 return _validate_clientsecrets(obj)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/py-3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py:99, in _validate_clientsecrets(clientsecrets_dict)
     97 for prop_name in VALID_CLIENT[client_type]['required']:
     98     if prop_name not in client_info:
---> 99         raise InvalidClientSecretsError(
    100             'Missing property "{0}" in a client type of "{1}".'.format(
    101                 prop_name, client_type))
    102 for prop_name in VALID_CLIENT[client_type]['string']:
    103     if client_info[prop_name].startswith('[['):

InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web".
```

Can someone tell me how to configure a credential on Google Drive API for accessing my Google Drive files with Jupyter notebooks?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Tip: Javascript origin is not the same as a redirect uri.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, ok! So, what should be the redirect uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that to access Google Drive files with a Jupyter notebook, it needs to be configured as a Desktop Application in the Type of Application field as follows:

[image: desktop app]

Another aspect to take care of is specifying the correct ports in the code I provided:

`lmao = {"auth_host_name":'localhost', 'noauth_local_webserver':'store_true', 'auth_host_port':[8890, 8891], 'logging_level':'ERROR'}`

A last caveat is to configure the `Test users` field on the `OAuth consent screen` tab and add the email with which we are accessing the Drive, as follows:

[image: OAuth config]

If you need to download not only files but also folders from your Google Drive, you can use this [code](https://github.com/hansheng0512/google-drive-and-python/blob/master/download.py).

Answer (score 1):

Checking the documentation of `Jupyter` [here](https://oauthenticator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/provider-specific-setup/providers/google.html) the `Authorized JavaScript origins` should be set to to your hub’s public address, and the `Authorized redirect URIs` should be set to the same but followed by `/hub/oauth_callback`.

So if your hub’s public address is `http://localhost:8890` then your redirect URI should be `http://localhost:8890/hub/oauth_callback`.

If that doesn’t work it will be better to contact their support line and request for that information.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using gdown:

```
pip install gdown

# to upgrade
pip install --upgrade gdown
```

Then you can just put the file id in like so:

```
!gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id[file id goes here]
```